# How to create checkbox-based price calculator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

Can you please give me examples how to create price calculator based on which checkboxes are selected using JS and jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/hof63n3k/

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1.99"> $1.99</input><br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2.99"> $2.99</input><br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3.99"> $3.99</input><br/>

Total: $<span class="total"></span>
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('input').click(function(){

        var total = 0;
        $('input:checked').each(function(index, item) {
            total += parseFloat(item.value);
        });
        $('.total').text(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: Some comments/explanation of the code would be nice, also your jsfiddle is incorrect, try: https://jsfiddle.net/hof63n3k/1/